# Without using Intel's tools, how can you determine the version of Intel Management Engine (ME) firmware installed?

Tags: windows, intel-core-i7

I know that Intel has a tool that will tell you what ME firmware version you are on, but I need to be able to determine from files, registry entries, or services which firmware version of ME a windows computer has. Is that possible? Furthermore, is it possible to detect if its provisioned or not, outside of a custom tool (again, using files, reg entries, or services)?

---

This is not a dupe. Detecting Intel ME firmware version on *nix is not the same as detecting it on Windows.

Comment: This may be listed in the BIOS, under System Information most likely. Otherwise, because it is firmware that is loaded on a specific piece of hardware, there does not actually have to be any software visible to the OS or files loaded on the hard drive for this to function in its basic forms, so it is possible there may not be any such files or registry entries and yet you'd still have ME on the system.

Comment: I don't understand, why not just run Intel's tool?  They provide a console version of it even, which is great for scripting.

Comment: just the limitations of my environment. If i could run em i would.

Comment: If you can't run 'em , then it's probably not your job to fix 'em. :)  Anyhow, good luck -- my guess is that there's no way to tell firmware versions based on native OS files/logs.

Comment: Not a dupe. Thats linux this is windows. Os dependent

Comment: @n00b Yes it is. The **answer** to that dupe is OS independent.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, I see, i didnt realize we flag questions as dupes on S.E. based on answers to other questions. Cool, you learn something new everyday.